# How to omit creating static Map for data caching?

Tags: java, caching, static, hashmap

I want to know if it is possible to omit creating cache with `static Map` instance.

***Here is snippet of my class***:

```
public class XpathEvaluator {
    private DocumentBuilder builder;
    private XPath path;
    private Document document;
    private static Map<String, List<String>> cachedXpaths = new HashMap<>();

    private XpathEvaluator() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        XPathFactory pathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        path = pathFactory.newXPath();
    }

    public static XpathEvaluator getEvaluator() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        return new XpathEvaluator();
    }

    public List multipleXpathResults(String xpathExpression) throws IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
        Logger.operation(StringUtils.appendStrings("Evaluating xpath expression: %1$s", xpathExpression));

        if (cachedXpaths.containsKey(xpathExpression)) {
            List<String> xPathValues = cachedXpaths.get(xpathExpression);
            Logger.info(StringUtils.appendStrings("For xpath: [%1$s] extract cached values: %2$s", xpathExpression, xPathValues));
            return xPathValues;
        }

        // ommited part
        cachedXpaths.put(xpathExpression, results);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Static reference keep groving during all time and I guess it can take too much space and has memory impact too much.

**Solution**:

```
private LoadingCache<String, List<String>> cachedXpaths = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .maximumSize(1500)
        .concurrencyLevel(5)
        .weakKeys()
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
                return createListByKey(key);
            }
        });

private static List<String> createListByKey(String key) throws Exception {
    return instance.getXpathValues(key);
}

public List<String> multipleXpathResults(String xpathExpression) throws Exception {
    Logger.operation(StringUtils.appendStrings("Evaluating xpath expression: %1$s", xpathExpression));

    List<String> results = cachedXpaths.getUnchecked(xpathExpression);
    if (results.isEmpty()) {
        Logger.error(StringUtils.appendStrings(
                "For xpath: [%1$s] extract cached values is EMPTY", xpathExpression));
        return results;
    }
    Logger.operation(StringUtils.appendStrings("Extracted xpath results: %1$s", results));
    return results;
}

private List<String> getXpathValues(String xpathExpression) throws XPathExpressionException {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    XPathExpression expression = path.compile(xpathExpression);
    NodeList list = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int index = 0; index < list.getLength(); index++) {
        Node node = list.item(index);
        String content = node.getTextContent();

        if (isContentWrong(content)) { // check if it is exactly string or number value
            Logger.error(StringUtils.appendStrings("XPATH value is EMPTY, for next node [%1$s]", node.getNodeName()));
            continue;
        }

        Logger.operation(StringUtils.appendStrings("Get NODE value: [%1$s]", content));
        results.add(content);
    }
    if (results.isEmpty()) { // log error if node result is empty
        Logger.error(StringUtils.appendStrings("XPATH result is EMPTY, for next xpath [%1$s]", xpathExpression));
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return results;
}
```

***I am wondering how to keep having cache and don't use static reference?***

Comment: As an option, you may consider using `WeakHashMap` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google guava](https://github.com/google/guava) for this type of caching:

```
Cache<String, List<String>> cachedXpaths = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(1000)
                .concurrencyLevel(5)
                .weakKeys()
                .build(
                        new CacheLoader<String, List<String>>() {
              // Call load method when there is a new key
                            public List<String> load(String key) 
                              throws Exception {
                                // Sample custom method to add a new key 
                                return createListByKey(key);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: what does `createListByKey(key)` mean? can you explain? And how to check if key has alredy added to map, now?

Comment: createListByKey is your custom method to provide the key/value which doesn't exist in the map. This part will be called if it doesn't find that key. otherwise it will be load key from the cached map directly without calling "load" method.

Comment: if I understand right this will be called to add new input to map. When this key will exist at map => it returns immediately. I can't catch how to `load()` adds value at the same time with key. can you help to implement it. Basis is at code snippet.

Comment: I am wondering to know efficiency of this cache if values for `List<String>` is empty. Does this cache remove it farther compare to list which has some values? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse a Java `Map` with a cache. It can be the storage component of a cache, but there is much more to a reasonable cache than storage.

If a cache "keeps growing all the time" and takes "too much space and memory", like you say, then it's not a cache any more. The problem has nothing to do with the static reference. Among other things, a cache needs a **limited memory** and a **strategy** to choose which old values **to remove** in order to make space for new ones.

You may also want to read [this document about caching best practices](http://java.dzone.com/articles/caching-best-practices) or use an existing caching solution like [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) or [Guava Cache](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: it is exactly `keeps growing all the time` now. Can you suggest some strategie for usage Soft reference or smt similar for solving this groving cache.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. My strategy for cache is to always load all the possible data with no restriction of memory and no strategy to refresh the data in it because that's how I need it. The problem OP confronts is to stop increasing adding data in the cache, otherwise is not a proper cache anymore.

Comment: @nazar_art use `WeakHashMap` as implementation for your `Map`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Yes, `WeakHashMap` is a possible **strategy for removal** - although one that might not always be suitable because it 1. doesn't have a hard memory limit and 2. might remove entries too early, if the key object don't exist continuously (even if an equivalent key object may be recreated later).